# Hosting a Simple Wcf Service in Console

Tags: wcf, console

I am trying to create a simple ConsoleApplication in which i would like to host a simple wcf service.

Here is the code for my

```
namespace HostConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost host = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(typeof(FirstWcfService.Service)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Sai");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then i have added an app.config which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="FirstWcfService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <endpoint address="FirstWcfService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="FirstWcfService.IService"/>
                <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9101/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When i run the host console app i get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled   Message="Could not find a
>   base address that matches scheme http
>   for the endpoint with binding
>   MetadataExchangeHttpBinding.
>   Registered base address schemes are
>   [net.tcp]."
>   Source="System.ServiceModel"
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri
>   relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding
>   binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase
>   host, ServiceDescription description,
>   ServiceElement serviceElement,
>   Action`1 addBaseAddress)
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader
>   configLoader, ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceElement
>   serviceSection)
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader
>   configLoader, ServiceDescription
>   description, String configurationName)
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration()
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses)
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type
>   serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses)
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>          at HostConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\navin.pathuru\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\Solution2\HostConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line
>   13
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Just wondering if how to fix this.
Thanks
N

Comment: you need to highlight your lines of code and XML and use the "code" button (101 010) from the editor toolbar to get good results - nicely formatted and syntax highlighted!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I think the problem is this:

- you have a base address for net.tcp
- you have a MEX http endpoint defined (but no http base address)

Basically if you want to use MEX over http, you need to supply either a **full address** for the MEX endpoint, or a http base address (if you only specify a relative address).

**Solution 1:** specify a full address for the MEX endpoint:

```
 <services>
    <service name="FirstWcfService.Service" 
              behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
       <endpoint 
           address="FirstWcfService" 
           binding="netTcpBinding" 
           contract="FirstWcfService.IService"/>
       <endpoint 
           address="http://localhost:9102/FirstWcfService/mex"
           binding="mexHttpBinding" 
           contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
        ......
    </service>
</services>
```

**Solution 2:** define an HTTP base address, too:

```
 <services>
    <service name="FirstWcfService.Service" 
              behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
       <endpoint 
           address="FirstWcfService" 
           binding="netTcpBinding" 
           contract="FirstWcfService.IService"/>
       <endpoint 
           address="mex"
           binding="mexHttpBinding" 
           contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
       <host>
           <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9101/"/>
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9102/"/>
           </baseAddresses>
       </host>
    </service>
</services>
```

**Solution 3:** use the mexTcpBinding instead

```
 <services>
    <service name="FirstWcfService.Service" 
              behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
       <endpoint 
           address="FirstWcfService" 
           binding="netTcpBinding" 
           contract="FirstWcfService.IService"/>
       <endpoint 
           address="mex"
           binding="mexTcpBinding" 
           contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
        ......
    </service>
</services>
```

Any of those three options should should solve it.

A word of caution: I find it quite risky to call your service behavior configuration "ServiceBehavior"......

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior" >
```

My recommendation: call your first and default configuation just plain "Default" (or "DefaultBehavior")

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Default" >
```

and only start giving out other names if you have multiple configurations.

Calling this `ServiceBehavior` just seems to be asking for trouble some time later on.....

Comment: Excellent, Thank you Mark.
I have added another Console app as a client to this solution.
Could you tell me how to consume this service that is in the ConsoleHost.
Thanks
N

Comment: Launch your first console with the service from cmd.exe; then go to Visual Studio, and in your client console app, choose "Add Service Reference" from the Solution Explorer context menu, and type in (or paste in) the URL where your service runs - that should then discover that service and create the necessary client-side bits for you to use it.