# Unexpected naming of client for a WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a simple WCF service with one interface and one class. When I add a service reference to my console apps, my WCF service class is not getting the expected name. My WCF service class name is `service1` but it is exposed to the client end as `Service1Client`.

Why is the word "**Client**" being added before my actual class name?  Do I need to add anything in my web.config for the service or in the app.config for the console end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "client" is your service proxy generated class that acts as a wrapper exposing the elements of your service and managing the underlying channels/communication for you. This is what you use in your service-consuming client applications in order to utilise the service.

Comment: i want the word client should not come rather class name "Service1" should expose then what i need to do.

Comment: in other wcf service example the word "client" is not coming then why in my case the word should come.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251538/hosting-a-simple-wcf-service-in-console